# Can symmetric rank two matrices be written as $WW^{\top}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-rank, symmetric-matrices

Suppose $A$ is a symmetric matrix of rank two. Then $A$ can be written as $A=vu^{\top}+zw^{\top}$. I could also write $A=UV^{\top}$, where $U$ and $V$ are $n \times 2$ matrices of rank two. I'd like to know if it's posible to express $A$ as $$A=WW^{\top},$$ for some $n \times 2$ rank two matrix $W$, given that $A$ is symmetric. I know that $A=UV^{\top}=(UV^{\top})^{\top}=VU^{\top}$, but don't know how to proceed from this point. Ideas?

Comment: Is $A$ a real matrix?

Comment: Readily for real $A$, it should be positive semi-definite to confine to this equality.

Comment: Every symmetric bilinear form can be diagonalised. Therefore you can always write $A=WDW^T$ for some $n\times2$ matrix $W$ and $2\times2$ diagonal matrix $D$. However, if the underlying field is not quadratically closed, you may not always get rid of $D$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are dealing with real matrices, it is not generally possible to express any symmetric matrix $A$ as $WW^T$, since the latter form implicitly invokes positive semi-definiteness and $A$ may not confine to such a structure. An example is
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&0\\
0&-1&0\\
0&0&0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
which is a rank-$2$ indefinite matrix, where no proper choice of $W$ is available such that $A=WW^T$. But, if $A$ is symmetric and positive semi-definite, Schur decomposition of $A$ yields
$$
A=UDU^T
$$
where $U$ is unitary and $D$ is diagonal with non-negative diagonal entries. If $A$ is rank-$2$, then
$$
D=\begin{bmatrix}
\hat D&0_{2\times n-2}\\
0_{n-2\times 2}&0_{n-2\times n-2}
\end{bmatrix}
$$
where
$$
\hat D=\begin{bmatrix}
d_1&0\\
0&d_2\\
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Now define
$$
S=\begin{bmatrix}
P_{2\times 2}\\
0_{n-2\times 2}
\end{bmatrix}
$$
where
$$
P=\begin{bmatrix}
\sqrt{d_1}&0\\
0&\sqrt{d_2}\\
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
and let $W=US$. You obtain what you wanted to prove. A similar approach cane be used for any general rank, symmetric positive semi-definite matrix $\blacksquare$

Comment: Thanks for the clarifying answer!

Comment: Happy to help!${}{}$